# MySQL query to calculate balance of increments/decrements to product IDs inventory stock level

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'log' where I'm tracking inventory changes. I'm using credits to denote an increase in stock and debits to denote a decrease (I think from an accounting principle, this is backwards, but it's what the client desires).

I need to calculate the balance of the debits and credits for each product (denoted by upc field) like a running total -- in other words, I want to show the log sorted by timestamp (or by the default order), and every time there is an increment or decrement to any product, show the resulting stock balance at that moment in time due to that specific increment or decrement.

I've been able to demonstrate this using this query, but only by singling out a specific product by adding its UPC code as a condition in the where clause:

```
SELECT 
    l.id,
    l.upc,
    l.credit,
    l.debit,
    @bal := @bal + credit - debit AS balance,
    l.timestamp
FROM log l, (SELECT @bal := 0) b
where upc = '677797003424';
```

I have a [fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4c8b/4/0)

The trouble is that when I take out the where clause, the calculation doesn't take into account that it's only supposed to operate on each set of UPC codes separately.

After some searching I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294393/calculate-the-each-productinkcode-stock) and the answer looks like something similar to what I may need, however, it is pertaining not to MySQL, but SQL Server. Also, I'm not sure the result would be the log/tracking format I've mentioned above. Specifically, what I want to avoid is showing the final balance on every line. If there are 999 of a product in stock, and four decrements later, there are 995 in stock, then each record that denotes  logging a decrement should not show the calculated balance of 995, but instead, the first decrement log should show the resulting balance of 998, the second should show 997, etc.

--- edit ---

Is there a way to accomplish this without the use of variables? Also, is it possible to have the log sorted by timestamp, so that the products are all mixed up, instead of being ordered together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
SELECT 
    l.id,
    l.upc,
    l.credit,
    l.debit,
    @bal := IF(@previous=l.upc, @bal + l.credit - l.debit, l.credit - l.debit) AS balance,
    @previous := l.upc,
    l.timestamp
FROM `log` l, (SELECT @bal := 0, @previous='') b
ORDER BY l.upc ASC, l.timestamp ASC
```

Edit:

In order to get negative values in @bal you can do the following

```
SELECT 
    l.id,
    l.upc,
    l.credit,
    l.debit,
    @bal := IF(@previous=l.upc, @bal + l.credit - l.debit, l.credit - l.debit) AS balance,
    @previous := l.upc,
    l.timestamp
FROM `log` l, (SELECT @bal := CAST(0 AS DECIMAL), @previous='') b
ORDER BY l.upc ASC, l.timestamp ASC
```

Comment: That might work as long as I make sure the beginning credit balances always are set before the debits start decrementing them. There's another problem as well -- what if I wanted to sort by timestamp first, so that the products are always mixed up, instead of being ordered together? Would it require another method besides the use of variables, and if so, would it be possible?

Comment: @LeeFentress I don't think you could achieve the ordering by timestamp straight from mysql, but it's a simple list sort in whichever language you use in your backend (php, ruby, etc...). As for negative values, see my edit

Comment: @LeeFentress don't forget to accept if you like the answer... :)

Comment: the query works in my database management tool and in SQL Fiddle, but when running it in phpMyAdmin or in my php script, it returns -1, for example, as the balance instead of 998, for example. It's as though one of the variables is not being evaluated correctly.

Comment: I did eventually get this solution to work with some modification into my specific implementation, so I've accepted the solution. Thanks @Damp!